# How to sync my profile on all Stack Exchange sites

Tags: support, profile-page

How can I sync my profile (info box) on all Stack Exchange sites?

In other words, I want to change my profile info box (I mean the empty box on the right to be filled in by user) on one of the sites, and want to copy this info to other SE sites without any hassle.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When editing your profile on one of the sites, you'll see an option "Save And Copy Profile To All Stack Exchange Accounts":

[image]

Using that, your changes are pushed to all other accounts, including your user name and profile image.

Your global Stack Exchange profile on [stackexchange.com](http://stackexchange.com) is synchronised with your oldest account. You can trigger that if needed:

- Click "Network profile" in the top right corner of your profile in any site
- Click "Sync with oldest profile"

[image]

Comment: In my case, my oldest profile has no data and I put most of my information in a different profile. What can I do to prevent it syncing and becoming completely blank?

Comment: Note: you no longer have to click the `Accounts` tab, with any tab selected the link will be under your About box.

Comment: (That *was* true, @Sparr, but meanwhile the answer has been edited. Care to delete your comment to prevent confusion? Thanks!)

Comment: Network profile synchronization with the oldest profile is no longer true: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86335/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314359/how-do-i-reset-location-info-and-avatar-in-my-profile-across-all-sites/314387#comment1030212_314387