# Profile info not synchronized

Tags: feature-request

I observed one minor thing. Profile info is not shared among SE. While reputation should obviously not be shared, the location and the website should. For example, on Area51 I result to be [in Tokyo](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/4713/stefano-borini), while on SO I am in [the Netherlands](https://stackoverflow.com/users/78374/stefano-borini).

Now, it may be claimed that I'm probably the only programmer who changes country every year since 10 years (and I'm still not done), but I still claim it as a technical inaccuracy (again, minor. I mean... SE is a technological jewel).

Comment: There's an option in your accounts tab that lets you [copy your profile across all sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81343/how-to-sync-my-profile-on-all-stackexchange-sites). It's not automatically synced on account of the fact that some users use different profile information, especially in their About Me, to highlight site-specific specialties. Also, here on Meta, you're in Zurich.

Comment: @Grace : I see the point. So this limits the issue to the location, which is the only information that should formally be shared across sites. Too little for being a problem.

Comment: @Grace : At least I'm not on Mars. yet.