# How can I edit my network profile?

Tags: support, network-profile

I made an account on Stack Exchange but I can't edit my network profile.

How can I edit this?

Comment: What kind of preferences you want to edit?
I hope this one was related with your question: [How to edit my preferences?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240521/how-to-edit-my-preferences)

Answer (score 9):

You can update the Stack Exchange network profile info by selecting update, than by choosing your profile from a Stack Exchange site:

[image]

Comment: I updated the image used to make clear where the link is exactly. It was unclear from the previous screenshot in my opinion. Good find and thanks for posting this!

Answer (score 5):

You can't edit the network profile independently.  It is synched to your oldest account (excluding Area 51).

Comment: I think ```"synched"``` is the wrong word, as it doesn't automatically update when you edit the profile of your oldest account.

Comment: @RaisingAgent it was in 2014, I think, but they've since changed the behavior as described in a newer answer.