# How can I edit my preferences?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, user-accounts, preferences

I was just wondering about Stack Exchange's account. I don't know how to modify the password and the other preferences which can be applied to all Stack Exchange sites. So far, I can edit some preferences, like the picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an edit link on your profile page:

> [image: edit link on profile]

Click it and you will be able to change your name.

There is also a "my logins" link that you can click - that will bring up a popup with several options. You should be able to change your Stack Exchange OpenId password through it, if you have one.

> [image: my logins]

Comment: Thank you, @Oded♦. Sorry, I was new user here.
Can I apply to all Stackexchange sites?

Comment: No need to apologize - everyone is new at some time ;)

Comment: As for applying to all SE sites - that's an option on the edit page, yes.

Comment: It worked, @Oded♦. Sorry for possible duplicate questions.