# "Save and copy changes to all public communities" does not include the stackexchange.com profile

Tags: bug, network-profile

How do I edit my **Network Profile**?

**Edit:** "Save and copy changes to all public communities" does not work for the Network Profile.

This looks like a bug. Is it supposed to not include `stackexchange.com`,
Especially since `meta.stackexchange.com` gets updated?

This is currently the only way to <s>edit</s> update it:
[image: Update Network Profile]

Comment: I thought it would change when you click "Save and copy changes to all profiles". I have never felt so betrayed :)

Comment: Wow @SonictheAnonymousHedgehog. It does indeed partially

Comment: The "Save and copy changes to all public communities" does apparently not include the non-meta Meta Stackexchange profile.

Comment: Is the non-meta ```stackexchange.com``` perhaps not a *public* community?

Comment: No, I'm afraid you cannot edit it directly; its contents have to be copied from another site. See my linked duplicate for instructions on how.

Comment: The second answer has the important information^^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "You can't edit the network profile independently. It is synched to your oldest account (excluding Area 51)."
>   - [Monica Cellio](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/243212/)

Comment: *not synched, maybe initially copied from ones first created account/profile.