# Is there a central place to edit StackExchange profiles globally?

Tags: support, stack-exchange, profile-page

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to sync my profile on all Stackexchange sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81343/how-to-sync-my-profile-on-all-stackexchange-sites)

I have profiles on quite a few different StackExchange sites. I've recently changed my email primary address, and I would like to update all of my profiles to the new address without going through and changing each one individually. Is there any kind of centralized management of SE profiles for things like this? I know about the "Network Profile" page, but that doesn't give me any way of pushing edits from one account to all the others.

Comment: Check out [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81343/how-to-sync-my-profile-on-all-stackexchange-sites). In short, everything except the OpenID of your profile can be copied to all of your associated accounts in one button click, in your `accounts` tab. ♪

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can do it:

1. Click your user profile
2. Click Accounts tab
3. Click Copy x profile to related accounts