# How do I reset location info and avatar in my profile across all sites?

Tags: support, profile-page

I would like to set my location message to the default message on all communities.
I would also like to make the icon the same as my Gravatar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you change your profile on one site, there are two buttons offered to save the information:

- Save changes just for this community
- Save and copy changes to all public communities

If you choose the second, it will do what it says: It will take the information in the current profile, save it, and then save it to all of the other communities where you have a profile.

Comment: Note it won't affect the network profile, which has to by synchronized manually.