# Save and copy changes to all communities

Tags: feature-request, profile-page

Adding "Save and copy changes to all communities" can be useful for some reason, *but* there is the "Save and copy changes to all **public** communities" button.

Comment: What specifically are you requesting?

Comment: @bobble See the answer below

Comment: @Fm, I'm not clear on whether you were asking for a button with this words to be added, a button with this functionality to be added, or to rename/refunction the existing button

Comment: While the answer was able to discern what you meant, I still think you should edit this to clarify precisely what you're asking for.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I reset location info and avatar in my profile across all sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314359/how-do-i-reset-location-info-and-avatar-in-my-profile-across-all-sites)

Answer (score 2):

This is the same button. The wording was just changed when Teams were introduced.

Note that it's also in the left navigation bar:

[image: Left nav bar with Public and Teams captions]

So "Save and copy changes to all public communities" means all the communities you have an account in, and not Teams profiles, if you have any.

Comment: Understoond, I need mod to change the status

Comment: @Fmbalbuena what status??

Comment: Status declined

Comment: See this answer, and your comment @sha: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/86335/282094 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314359/how-do-i-reset-location-info-and-avatar-in-my-profile-across-all-sites/314387#comment1030212_314387  - the public Network Profile isn't updated, so the button text isn't very accurate and your answer is incomplete.

Comment: @Rob it is, network profile isn't a real profile it's only a portal.

Comment: It isn't, and it's a site with a profile.